# Tableau Embed into external application

Tags: javascript, api, embed

We basically have an interface that uses SAPUI5 frameworks and is in JavaScript. How does one go about embedding a simple dashboard into their user interface? I know how to embed a dashboard into a webpage using tableau's javascript API. Anyone have experience on this / advice?

Comment: how would you use tableau API in a page without UI5?

Comment: hey I am trying to do the similar thing do you guide me on this.. i am not able to login on tableau server